# Remove rows with incomplete levels that are not NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I've been reviewing possible solutions for a while in StackOverflow, but I have to ask for help on this one.

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D"),
             B = c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F2", "F3", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", 
             "F4"))
```

I would like to filter it to keep only those rows with complete levels, like below:

```
df_new <- data.frame(A = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                 B = c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4"))
```

Please notice that the filtering of `Col1` is subject to the condition that `Col2` must have all levels `lvls <- c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4")`, so using `dplyr::filter` or `subset` is tricky. 
It is a long (and dynamic) dataset, so I would not like to do this manually. Thanks in advance for your kind attention.

Comment: I am sorry, in my question I meant to say " Remove rows with incomplete levels that are not NAs".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about either of these:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(B)) == length(levels(B)))

df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(B) == length(levels(B)))
```

> ```
>        A      B
>   <fctr> <fctr>
> 1      A     F1
> 2      A     F2
> 3      A     F3
> 4      A     F4
> 5      C     F1
> 6      C     F2
> 7      C     F3
> 8      C     F4
> ```

Or, if you need to worry about missing values:

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(B[!is.na(B)])) == length(levels(B)))

df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(B, na.rm=TRUE) == length(levels(B)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[nlevels(droplevels(B))==max(nlevels(B))], A]
#   A  B
#1: A F1
#2: A F2
#3: A F3
#4: A F4
#5: C F1
#6: C F2
#7: C F3
#8: C F4
```